# Is there a way to check for duplicate entries in values of an array in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapbox

I am trying to remove the duplicate values from a deeply nested array. I've put the structure of the database down below. I want to compare the location of the steps with eachother and check for duplicates. I was thinking about using `db.collection.aggregate`, but it becomes a problem when trying to search through all steps since `{ $unwind: '$mapbox.routes.legs.0.steps' }` requires a specific index for the steps as far as i know.

```
"mapboxRoute" : {
        "routes" : [ 
            {
                "distance" : 105375,
                "duration" : 8261.3,
                "weight" : 11365.5,
                "weight_name" : "routability",
                "geometry" : "iv||H_{f^w@b@AFDZHb@DTBL?B@LN`ALx@BPA@WPEBc@X[PIFADFb@T|AHd@DZL~@@DF\\Hd@DVFVBPDL?BBL@DBFJb@FV?@BHDL@FKBa@`@MJx@y@@FKBa@`@MJi@b@WN]ROLSPWkAFS@s@Mg@Lf@Ar@GRVjAIHKJ_@b@INEFI^CHMPA@]\\IFa@\\s@l@MJMLIHe@b@_@^w@j@KFEBk@d@EDEDEBEBEBKJKHEBMLIHEDQDQLGFMHTQGFMHq@d@e@^GFg@b@ABQNCBIFWRQNm@h@QNa@\\ONGF?FAZBJv@vDd@xBd@fBj@hA`A`Cf@lAz@xBd@r@Z\\PRE\\CXCPB`A?r@A|@EdAR?DqABmDC]Ge@Me@m@yA}@wBiBeEo@uAg@cBMa@oAgGAKOU{AnAIFKJNRNMnAeABJNt@BNb@pBb@tB@BH\\ZhADF\\p@FN`A`Cf@lAHTFLDNb@dALRV^BBVXWYVZRPLHHDHDHDJCRCLAPG~@UNGLEDCRGPGJEl@UJEREBAVA\\BLBHF@@PPHJJJNPBDFLBBL^Qc@BBL`@DJBDHPDPHNDJHPFJ@BBDPRPRNNRPBBHFNPDJP\\BDNf@@D`BlHHTBLP^T^BBRVFFDBVLj@VLF~@b@FBGCHDJDB@ZJJF`@PTJNJZN^ZJHVVRTFJRVr@bAHJf@v@DFDF@BJL`@n@l@~@RXT^T\\f@t@FH@@LRLRjAjB`@r@r@hA~AhCVj@kD_Gr@hA~AhCVj@Zl@BFXj@`@z@Xp@N^HTXx@FPVz@Vv@Tt@@Fd@xAPn@Pn@@FNp@Px@DRJ`@TfATfAb@xCRrAHj@T|AXhBXtBFb@Hp@Lr@f@`DBVBPl@tE@Fr@|Fu@eG@Fr@~FLjAVpCBJb@vDNhA?DHl@Fh@?J?\\@`@?\\?VA\\?@?\\AR?FAJEh@Ef@UjB[nCK|@KjACPEd@QnBYdDC\\CVALO|APkBALO~AEf@ABEj@CLETA@IVCDCFGHGHEBOLA@QHGBIBKBAAS?E?MEGCKGMKAAMOKOAEK[CIG]EQ?MCa@?C@i@?GFYG`@?GFYD]DMDMBGJUDIDCRSLGHETEBAb@A@@pAHp@Hb@D~APt@LtAVhANTDhFbBxHfCZJXJJBPFb@L~@Vj@PvAl@lA`@hAj@XRNLZVFDVXdAjAeAkAdAjAVXPR@@RNRNb@ZHFLFTLPHNHB@THTHJBFBRDVFR@V@R@T@D@HAb@?NAH?HA`@Ia@H`@I|@O~@OTE\\GLATCLCB?H?NAL?V?JAJBTBRDH@VHZHRFl@Rt@Vp@TdA^t@TPFp@Rx@TzBp@pBl@qBm@pBl@lBj@F@l@TbFfBXHzGpBfD`Ab@LrCl@`B^J@PDTFHB`DbAdDdAl@Rl@RTF\\L~@Xr@TF@hB`@~@T|@PhATp@LXDl@FnALoAMnALR@~@DvAHdADd@BzFHlLJhV`@\\@B?zLLJ@L?X?V@~BBnKPbCDbHJpBD@?p@@jBBnCDxABrBDpBDzGLxA?xFBN?n@?H?r@@r@@s@Ar@@h@@d@@f@@F?j@Ah@A^A^AR?f@Cv@Cd@ALALANAv@Ib@EPAFAp@Kx@Kh@IRCRE`@GVEp@M`@Ga@F`@G`@ITEFA`@Ov@W\\Mh@Qr@Wn@SpCkAp@Yx@]fBu@r@Yt@[t@[l@WNEJE^On@U`@OJE@ALEdBq@RITKd@Q|@c@fAi@HEqAn@fAi@HEbAg@d@Wd@Sv@a@jC}AjAq@TOp@]~@e@rCyAZQ|CwAhFaC`EmBvFiC|CwADC`Aa@JElAi@ZO|@a@fBq@|Am@dA]tAe@bBi@DA~DiA_EhA~DiAj@Or@StBk@bAY\\KHCr@YLEPILEBA~Ao@DAp@YfAe@`Bq@BAl@Yj@WfD}AxDgBjB{@LG|As@hEoBLGLGPINIa@RPINIx@a@tCwApDgBjDeBDC^Sf@YJGJGnBgAhF}CnDuBLIf@]d@[FCf@a@n@g@`@[NQ|@_AhAmAFKj@y@V]NUp@gA`@q@@Cf@y@d@}@e@|@d@}@n@gALWTg@Rg@BEZs@Rg@HQxBgFdB}DfBcEdGiNBEL]N]\\w@Xq@JWRg@@Ex@kBz@kBPc@z@kBJUJULW@C\\m@`AcB?AlAkBmAlB?AlAkBh@{@\\e@r@cAj@y@\\e@PWfBcC^g@PWfAyAZa@zAsB|B}C~@oAvC}DBEnAwArA}AdBoBDGXY\\]lBuBzA}AfCkCbBcBxD{Dp@q@DEpEsErBuBsBtBrBuBh@i@~CcD`DaDb@c@dAgARSv@w@tEyElAmAjAmAfBgBnAoATWLMBCPQzB}BzB}BhEkEr@s@rC{CNOpBuB~CyCpAmA`@e@bFuFRYlAcB`A{AZg@Ve@s@lAZg@Ve@h@cAb@y@dAsBhGsLz@cBj@iA`CwEvF}KXk@Zm@bAsBdAqBzBqELShCgFTg@Xg@Tc@~ByE~AcDdEkI`EgIrDoHJUd@_AtAoCtAqC`@w@a@v@`@w@FMb@k@l@{@Za@f@}@JSx@wALU`@o@FIPSFGLKJEJCLAD?F@LBB?FDJFB@DFJJBDDFFPBBDPFXDn@@h@?DIl@KZJ[KZCHEHe@x@EHg@r@iBhCIHC@C?C?GAKBIHCJCPAB?H@H?DBH@BFH@@DBHNJ\\Lp@HZH`@@FLd@@HNd@@Bj@lANPDLf@rAJ\\BFHVbBtFL\\M]L\\J^dE~M`@rAfB|Fx@hCHVL\\j@dBZ~@J\\DLHb@EDABAFCH?F?PBJ@DDD?@FB@@FAB?FEL^@DJVLPNTVv@HVNTj@`AXf@NLLL][NLLLf@f@RRXXhChCjHzGz@v@xJbJFHFFr@n@LTPP`AbA`@b@@?JHHH@@JJJL^\\v@n@XV\\\\LLn@t@VXLPd@n@b@t@DHf@fAFLP`@Rj@h@|APf@@F`@z@CF?DBMCF?DAH@F?B@HBHHF@BF?D?Dl@F\\Hl@DPP~@Jj@Nt@DP@H^vBz@~ETpAJh@Lr@Ll@Rr@Rn@BFRh@Rd@N^LVd@`AZp@DFf@p@g@q@f@p@b@n@NT`@\\l@h@PLjLlJfHfFBBPLJHhAz@r@h@rCxBtDlCzAfARN@@LD`A^JDB@PBdAPRDH@r@Br@BHANAr@CPABAZE[DZElC_@|Dc@PAFAB?J?F?BF@BBD@BD@@@H?FEFIBKlCl@BBxAj@B@TLd@VHF^XNL\\VLLBBZZ^`@nBrBl@p@hBlBJHuBwBhBlBJHrBfBBBh@j@l@n@LJx@t@^\\rApAzDvDbKzJxCrCdAdADFDDZb@Zd@TZ?@T\\HLNVx@z@JLCL?F@J@HDH@DFD@?H?DA@CFGLHd@X\\PB@JDKEJDJDb@LFBfB^~A\\lDz@^HfAT\\Jr@Pv@Pj@NNDAP@P@BBJ@@JHF@BAD?FIBCDM@OH@lCb@H@LB~FhAh@JTDRD?H?BBJ?@DH?@FFD@?X?B@v@@dAAeA@dA?N@vA?D@f@?^@\\NzJDvC@DD|CLrGT|K?P@L?J@XBPDLDNGHABCNAF@F?FBHDJDBB?B@FAHE@EBE@G@O?AAIEOJSDKBG@CEJBG@CJOBEBCHIRWJMNOBELOTY@AZa@BCr@q@|@}@LKJIVUZUROHGBCn@]HANEBANGDAb@Gt@Mh@I`Ba@lCo@RETGtA[rA[sAZrA[@ATGHCb@MZIB?\\Kb@Kf@Mv@U~Aa@FCDANE`FkAfEcAVGhK}BdK}BxCq@vCo@r@OzBi@hAWPERGz@U@JBFDFFB@?B?BAG@B?BABAFI@I@C?K?CAK?AGKGEI?Y_Ba@gCUuAa@{Ci@yDg@yD_A}G{@mGCOE]AOCY?CAg@A[?EBm@@GFk@BSBO@EFYJe@jCkKBQ@IAa@?j@@IAa@AWI_@}B}FAA}AcE_BcECEGQKYy@{BEMUo@Yy@AEEQQw@Qy@CIQw@Qw@CKI_@I]ACr@o@d@[VUHKDIZe@lAqBDGDG`@q@rAiBt@cAfA{AJMt@s@v@s@w@r@v@s@BCLONSHMIYHKHX^i@@CDMLORYXa@VYLILIFCZMf@MDARGBCLINMLILG\\Qx@a@nAe@jAa@LEp@Q|@WDAfA[B?dAa@iA`@B?dAa@v@[l@UDCj@Yz@e@d@WBAn@m@n@k@\\[x@y@VWJM`@m@FId@{@dAkBJQ@CJGHGRCFA^AJ?XCNCXGRERMHCFGXUNMOLNMHGFMHSLWBEFSHWFU@SD_@@MCa@AOCKGYGS?GGe@CQ?M?m@Ao@DgAF}C?G@y@@ICYCc@GUWiAG[?AF\\G[?AEc@Gm@Ca@CUAGGQAAMQIOGIECOEa@MAAKGGECEIQEMEKEUGQ?COw@QeAGYIe@AGAIGi@Fh@Gi@CUEg@ASE}@G{@I_BGoAEu@?ICc@?WAC?W?k@Am@?c@?a@?CCg@Eo@CUSeBSaBGk@CUACCQI_@Yy@[_AM[h@zA[_AM[]_AAAQYYi@KQKQCCGWI_@Me@Qu@Qu@a@kA]cACIy@iC?AIQWo@AC[c@a@m@mAcBiA_BIMACGOEKAGGSEQDPEQW{AG]AUEY?E?O?W?[?Y?W?O?CAMESCKKUUm@ACYk@g@aAQ]O[IOQOCAg@WSMRLSMCAGIGKAAEOK[Oe@Sm@Og@qBsGMa@MUOWKOEKM]ACCOEWAEAc@AG?[?wA?s@AGCc@SqAOkBAGW{DO{CA]CcC?Q@y@@WDyA?IGzB@WDyA?I@c@AUCw@?AeAeGOo@Oq@Uc@Ue@sB{CA_@?GDk@B_@^cFDc@AECUAGGEMKUCG?BqA@{@?G?oB@uA?_@?e@?KAkBCuCASSyHGwDZpNSyHGwDKyIC{AAoF?aF?GBiDBgAHmDD{@R_F@KVmENwCPsC@IVwCLmAZ}BTgBf@qDXmBBODQ@CH@HCFIDM@MAG?CCKACCEGCBUCTBUDU`@gDd@mCPaA\\_Bf@aCb@qBfBgH@GRw@F[H]DY^kBDYLs@V{AHa@P_BVqBFy@ReCXaDHeBDo@DsADiA@KDgCBq@?[?cA?g@?f@?g@?eBAiA?YCgBAICu@HAdBUTE^Ex@AxAE^AzAGnDC|ACbAApCE~BExBCxBAF?xCK`DEbIM@?dFF|GH|LNbA@fJNdJNl@@l@@bEN|AHnAHD?jBP~Fn@B?dCT`AJr@D{Fg@dCT`AJr@DL@pAFtA@rAC@?VADA^CTAJAF?NC\\EJAb@ETCBAFAh@KrAWf@KlAa@t@UlB_AHEdBgAhAs@j@]VQb@YHEDCf@SnA_@lCy@mCx@lCy@jCy@hN}D`K}ClC}@bO{EhEyA`@O~Cw@pA[lA[@?xBm@NE`A_@ZMTKlAq@@AdDmC@Al@_@@Ar@[NGLGj@EH?B@BJ@@DDBDB?HBHCHG@CBGDO?CERDO?C?O?AAOGMGGEEG}C?A?_@@eK?}D?cA@UJoDJ{ARoCTsA\\sBt@eDj@qBjAyCx@_BrQe]pA}BWW_@EIDu@hAOLYJsJZa@C]IqBgAaAcAg@q@kBmD{@yAc@k@aLfKwG|FyGlG_AdAxEvMxGfKlArA|DvDr@d@~@\\rAJfC^TsADURoABMVgAXoABMj@qBDMf@mA\\}@x@_Bh@cArB{DtLeUpA}B@Ab@aAbCuEp@iAR]S\\R]|F}KNWbAmBFM|@mB@AFW\\qABIZ}ADWJkABUPsBDmDC_AA_@ASUsLc@qPAu@OcECu@S_CI}@CYC[c@sDIu@CYUiBThBUiBSgBCUAIAKIk@w@qGGg@E[{A_LMy@S_BMy@Mo@Qy@Ig@Uk@GSUo@]u@DQ?K?G?QEOEGCE?AEAIEA?K@A@GDMYQ]EIDHEIAA[a@EGIK_@g@KMY[s@u@AA]]CCe@g@{BaCkAmA_BeBq@q@m@q@qAwAaCiCEEo@q@GIIEIGSICAOECAOC?E@EAG?CAKCGCCCAEAG@E@ABFEE@ABCDAFA@?L?H@D@BBD@BGREPGNENGNCBKLOPQTWVc@d@A@cArAeAtAEDk@x@s@bAcArAaAtAA@ILk@t@s@~@[c@IMo@sAe@}@MULTMUUe@CEIUGOEWCMAKC[AM?Q?[?W?GBa@De@DODQFUBEHOLUV]@Ad@c@LMvA}A\\a@NOTWDE|F_FBC`@]a@\\`@]NMPOHGjAeAjAeAjC_CdA}@FGpEmDRQ~AiAfAw@bAi@bAk@HEZO\\OBA|@a@l@SLGx@W@?h@OTGx@QB?|@QPCl@I|@Kd@GXE~@I~@KNAn@I|@IRCj@Gn@GD?`BQpBUqBTpBUpBUxBUzBWdBShAMZCrBWr@Cb@AhACJ@P?T?R?pBF^@vBNf@DLBvAVv@LXDp@PvA^^H|A`@\\HzBl@bCp@XHx@Jp@Hl@HXDZ@u@GXDZ@fADb@@V@P@P?D@fO\\pUh@vADjIRN@d@HfBZvAFp@HH@VFLBHBPFHBHFPLPJ^^BBFHLNLPj@dAfAvBb@z@@@LRMSLRFLDBPPBB`@VTFXJB?hAL\\BHJLHFLBFBFBP?P?V?BFLCt@AFKbBAXOlBAFKr@Ip@Kt@?DERUnAG\\Kf@UnAQ~@sAnHEVmB_Aa@YOUESAO?M?IHo@N_AFa@Hk@Jm@MCUtASnAEXIf@?^?NBNBLDJHLf@\\lAv@^TCLLm@mB_Aa@YOUESAO?M?IHo@N_AFa@Hk@Jm@MCUtASnAEXIf@?^?NBNBLDJHLf@\\lAv@^TCLI^a@vCAFGv@SdB?DKjAEj@AT?BG~@A\\AP?PAPAVAd@E~@Av@Ad@AlB?fA?TBnD?BFfBBlB?LBlC?PBlB@t@?\\?z@?dA?D?d@?PAT?\\Cn@APGz@AJGl@CNJ}@Gl@CNGb@EXG\\Ml@ADQv@Od@ENKVGNM^GHYn@MZKT_@z@IR_@bAGTSt@Or@CPG\\G\\CTE`@CPEj@CTCp@ALCd@?PA^AV?P?d@?F?XBd@@d@@TVbEv@~LBTCUBT@TTdDRzC^fGv@jLrCvc@d@hHv@rLlAhR\\jFJxADl@KDA@EHABCHAD?J?H?D?H@BBH@BDH@?HFH?HC@ADGBCBG@I@CCL@I@C@IAG?C?MZMZILCdDu@hCk@hAk@RIxGcDBAzH{DrHuDJEFCjFkCnAm@^Q|Ae@BAfBg@^GnASBA|AOtAG|EOlM_@xCItHSTA|GSx@Cn@AHA`@CTCF?@H@FBFB@GIBFB@@@D@@AB?DEDM@KJ?`@Ap@A@?dAEhAE@?zAET?dACB?v@Cz@Cb@A~HUtJYb@DJ@NB`@HZFDB^J`@Lj@PtA^`@L`@FRDR?P@R?e@AP@R?NAr@GREXGr@KRE|@Kj@AR?B?ZFVDD@j@X@B`@d@JLLTNXHPDLNb@Lj@FXJr@XpBR~AVjBFd@VvBHp@LdALnAHz@RjBLnAMoALnABTR|BFn@HdAd@bG?Dh@fEZbChAjGr@xD~AtIF\\@JBDHJFJDJD@LF@?H?L?NAJ?VGl@Mp@QfAWTIb@Q@?ZGZEB?^Ac@@B?^AX?D?PBTDJ@DBRFl@VLDxAj@NFPFVFTFZHLDzAVv@NXDb@@l@B|AFjCFpCFbBBZ@nB@V?N?R?R?F?Hn@Qo@F?Hn@PvATdBj@~D\\~BD\\PjAtAvJHf@@H@HBFBF@DLVFJHJLL@BDBNHVDD@D?H?F?B?JCNEPKHCJELG@?NALAM@LAD?JBB@HDNFHFDBFHDFHR@B|@vB~@xBlE|KpBhFp@bBFRRh@Nh@Jd@Jb@@FFr@BX?L@b@?^?HCn@Cz@]COOAoAQGcBFKEGM?k@xB@N@?z@@nANN\\BCj@ADQpCRwCADQpCg@tHIpAGfAMbCEfAEx@MlCItBE`AAl@EnAGrDMvFG|HCpC?~K?bF?ZLbR?\\@T?VY~IA`AChAA~@@|@HjABb@BJV~AW_BV~ARfANz@@LBj@Fx@FdAD|AHjCBz@Bt@JvCHfCXzIRvFPlFBhANbDLlCNtC^jIRvEBZH~A@TNdC^pGV`EJfBf@dIs@mLJfBf@fIl@bIb@jF`@bFD\\r@jIBVf@dF@Hb@bEf@xEx@|Ht@jHPlB@PHrABh@@ZHlBNzCJxBFtAFtANfDBp@Bj@B\\Ft@@JJt@?BNr@BNFTJ^BBXr@P^@Bd@~@LTMULTLTHPTn@F\\Lz@Lz@@FJ~@J~@@HHx@Bf@DhA?P@d@@~@@|@A`A?dD@rDAr@?T?BAVARAh@Ch@G^EXCFGXCHM\\Pg@CHM\\KVCBQXILCBQNMH_@TMBg@HA?[A_@GMA]G[EA?cACe@AS@Q@]HKDYJ]LUHc@Ze@Zy@t@C@uDpDONQNA@SNGF_@D[AMA@u@A]A]Ck@FCDCJQDW?YWfADCJQDW?YPMDE`@[JIdAo@JGv@e@LIt@e@DCf@U~@a@p@Yd@SBAv@YVIBAd@OLEz@WLEh@Ov@Wf@MhA[NCFCHCn@Qd@KFCm@Nd@KFCPGNE^Kb@Q`@MfAa@|Ai@t@YbE_BnFsBHCnAg@lAg@RIpCgA@Ad@Od@Q~@[z@[TGRGj@Oh@OFAv@OtBc@^G|@Q}@P|@Q~@SDAx@WPGfA]b@O\\OZMZOLEBARIjAg@nAk@rB{@f@UNGFCDCl@YdAg@JGNKRM\\SJI`@_@^]^]HGTSURTSTSFGr@c@b@YDETUBCb@e@DEPW^i@`@k@BCHMPWDIBANQH?@?LHHNJRUTeA~AmBnCqAtAuBfBaDfCmAn@gFjBiDt@i@`@[aASmAEYFCBEBI@IAKAICEEEEAG@EDCFCH?H@JBFDFDBDADXRlAZ`Ah@a@hDu@fFkBlAo@`DgCtBgBpAuAlBoCdA_BTULGBAb@QVK\\K@GBo@@S?CBQBUBQFc@Gb@Fc@BIF]FUL[Xm@|AqDl@wAHQJY\\}@Vq@HS@Ec@g@YYOSIIMOWYOOeAoAm@u@ACQWGIYe@ACIOEKACMUYw@]gACGGQFPGQSm@OYYg@ACm@q@CA_@[YUGCk@YGCUEe@GO?m@CiEGu@CM?E?EOEU?S@QFgC?IFyAJcD@S@o@Bk@DO?ANIHEJAK@JAZLP@@?HGDAB@TN~@\\fCv@vBn@x@Vt@VDhC@b@DtADfD@bAOb@Wf@GJq@s@y@q@{@a@{@MqIOKc@HoDT{GD{ADQVOLAZLP@PIDMf@}GHs@BY@CBW@GJ]BML_@DKJOLSLOBEHABAJCPEBAp@Ol@MDCFCLQ?ADK@SCO?E[qDQiBKiAGi@IiACUL~AIiACUCO{AaQo@iGCSAKCi@@U?[@[Dc@\\aDtAyMXuCHy@@YNsB\\yF?S@QGIEGIIAAuAk@YKSKwAm@iAg@IE[I}DkAgBg@AASKIEMGCCaB_B`B~AaB_B}A{As@s@GIg@q@EIWg@]o@Q]?CG]ACIMCAOKWQCA_@IQCG?AI?CCCEEE?AS@_@@c@B{@H{@F_@Li@`@kAZaARq@?CDIfAeEFSb@mBHe@Jm@Fm@FaA@IDmB@q@@i@@YAX@Y@iATc]?GBw@@IBm@F{@@KDWHu@@CFa@F]FYJe@La@FSBILa@BER_@rAiCZi@bCoEzAoC@CtA}BtF}JZk@`A}At@kAXc@PQMa@a@uA_EoNQe@O_@IWCEi@kACEe@y@d@x@e@y@}B}DAEM_@AEG]G[CKCYASAO?M?S@]?GBWBQBUDQNq@LWjAeCHQzAqCFIlF{JJSrAkCJ[b@sATq@T}@T{@DSToAFc@c@fCDSToAFc@PqADy@NyCDs@@_A?o@?e@M{SEuHGuHCsGEkG?EAo@EaIEqJC}DC}DIoKAq@Cc@EwAK}BCSIoAKqACUi@eF{A{NAEsAeMuAcMGi@Fh@Gi@K_A]{CEc@UwBg@qEg@qEUyBW}BIo@Gq@OmAsBwRu@cHu@uG[iCaA^o@^eQ|N{GxFu@p@e@f@a@f@iGjI]Zk@VSJMDKLKRIVKRONkElEiBxBuBlB}EbFa@j@]v@Sx@Gl@IpCMDGHEVC`@MlEAv@At@AzE@f@BNDRNPBqJRmIHqCFm@Ry@\\w@`@k@|EcFtBmBhByBjEmENOJSHWJSJMLERKj@W\\[hGkI`@g@d@g@t@q@zGyFdQ}Nn@_@`A_@~@]FCXQd@YvBmAFEvEsCPK~BwAVU\\W@APOb@_@hEkF`KgM~AoB|AoB}AnB~AqBBEFG`BsB~AqBkAmC_E}H[o@Sc@K]?CAIAK@G@Q@G@GFWHg@@A^kB\\eBBOVoAZaBDOpAuGpAwG?CDQv@aEv@aE@ETiAWnA@ETiAVqAH_@VwABGJa@T{@NYBE@Cf@kAPc@DGFE@?DAB?B@FADGDGBK?K@G@KFKrA{AJMHGZW\\SDAVMJC\\KDAxEaAlFiAVGXMHABFBBB?D@B?BADEBG^KvMmCXIh@O\\OFCFEZO^S\\SyAv@ZO^S\\Sp@e@h@g@f@g@DGl@s@n@}@BGBALUPYd@_ABGn@oABCR_@HMFMXe@n@iAJQ^s@O]Sa@IQEI]o@Yk@MUKOGKMOKMMKk@e@m@g@AAYSUSTRUSWS]WAAWW[Y_@c@Y[CC_@g@[e@CC[g@[g@AAUc@Yk@GMWi@Ym@Qa@EGQUIKCGIU_@cAg@wAEMSo@So@Uq@?CTt@Uq@?Cm@sBK]W{@]oAIa@K_@S}@U{@GYWqAG]i@kC]eBGWi@iDEUEUIi@a@_CMq@CQOaASmAW_BG_@YyB[yBK_AOsAS_BEe@WoCIcAIgARjCIcAIgAOoBi@qHe@cHa@wFAKKyAAOIeACa@Ec@Gy@Cc@OqBSeCEs@AIAiACgA?[Ac@Ae@CeAAs@?E?y@@sA?q@?MB_AC~@BaADeA@SFgADk@?I@YBe@?O?O@a@?IA_@A]?CA[C]AQCc@?CCQAU}@TKDg@PG@s@Rk@LMDc@H]Hk@NKBODC?u@RGB}@T|@U}@TODMBe@LoCp@kD|@I@MBMBI?E?K@K?c@?w@GKAmBWsCi@aAIIAYGe@OGCCAECGE?ACICEACGEG?GBCBA@CD?DABAH?D@B@JBF?JCNE`@If@EVK`@Sn@ADKTQ^\\u@KTS^IREDEHORCBURQPA@STSVg@h@oArAA@a@b@a@b@]^[Zy@z@e@d@CDAHAJEECBONYXA@_@^MLGHCLAHAJ?B@L@R@PCRCNEHMFC@cANbAOcANeAPwAV",
                "legs" : [ 
                    {
                        "distance" : 105336.1,
                        "duration" : 8259.5,
                        "steps" : [ 
                            {
                                "distance" : 132.5,
                                "duration" : 50,
                                "geometry" : "iv||H_{f^w@b@??AFDZ??H`@?@DT??BL???B@LN`A??Lx@??BP",
                                "name" : "Mariaplaats",
                                "ref" : null,
                                "destinations" : null,
                                "exits" : null,
                                "driving_side" : "right",
                                "mode" : "driving",
                                "maneuver" : {
                                    "location" : [ 
                                        5.117934, 
                                        52.089493
                                    ]
```

Does someone know how I can compare the locations of the steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I stopped making a seperate file for connecting with mongodb and cleaning the database and started using the already existing API to create a call. In this call I looped through the steps in the database and mapped the location to a key. After that I check if that key already existed and pushed that index to a duplicate array.

Then I proceeded to loop through the duplicate list and spliced the duplicate entries from the list with steps. After that I ran the following function to update the entry: `await routeSchema.updateOne({ _id: route._id }, { $set: route });`